# Expose a Class to JMX which resides in a transient dependency jar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, jmx, spring-jmx

I have a Java Web App (Spring) with some classes exposed to JMX. Let's call this project 'A'.

A has a dependency jar called B. B in turn has a dependency C.

Now I would like to expose a Class in C via JMX. So I decorated the class with the following

```
@ManagedResource(objectName = "A:name=myClassInC")
public class MyClassInC
```

But this doesn't seem to have any effect and the MyClassInC doesn't show up in the JMX console along with the other classes that are visible from A. The Spring JMX configuration actually resides in the context files of A. So I'm guessing that classes in C should also pick up the same configuration and show up in the JMX console. I'm wondering how I can fix this. Thanks!